# Upgraded Selenium to 2.50.1 with Conductor Framework & ChromeDriver is throwing an exception

Tags: java, selenium, conductor-framework

I upgraded the selenium_version in the [Conductor Framework](https://github.com/conductor-framework/conductor) pom.xml to: 2.50.1

I needed to update Selenium to make use of the FileDetector for remote uploads, e.g:

```
((RemoteWebDriver) driver).setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
```

The change works perfectly with PhantomJS locally, and my Hub; but when I try to run ChromeDriver locally, I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/service/DriverService$Builder
```

Comment: What Selenium version have you upgraded from? And what version of ChromeDriver are you using?

Comment: I'm using the maven repository for selenium-java and selenium-chrome-driver. Both were at version 2.43.1

Comment: What about the `chromedriver` application (.exe, etc.)?

Comment: It's version 2.20 for Mac

Comment: Have you checked all your dependencies (I'm assuming Maven or equivalent) to ensure that you're not pulling in a mixture of Selenium versions? Almost certainly this is some 2.50 JARs being overridden by 2.43 ones, and conflicting with other 2.50 ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the conductor framework was missing some dependencies.. primarily, the `selenium-remote-driver` dependency.

That dependency (as well as others) [was added](https://github.com/conductor-framework/conductor/commit/d33fbd7ceabe63a2c7f92c0ea43628bf311c9346) and a new 2.2.2 version was [published](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cio.ddavison%7Cconductor%7C2.2.2%7Cjar).

Update your Pom file to have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.ddavison</groupId>
    <artifactId>conductor</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and you should be good to go!

Comment: no problem @risteard, my pleasure ;)  mind shooting me an email? (you can find it from my github profile (found on my SO profile) I had a couple questions for you, if you didn't mind